# Wordpress/PHP: if () {} not working with is_page()

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

This is a WP template made from scratch.

I have this inside the *head* :

```
    <?php

    if (is_page(about-contact)) {
        $cssDirectory = get_stylesheet_directory_uri();
        echo "<link rel='stylesheet' href='" . $cssDirectory . "/scss/onepage-scroll.css'/>";
    } else {
        echo '';
    }

    ?>
```

There is another on like this for a script at the bottom of the *body*.

However, it is behaving as if it is always true for every page I have made a template. The only one not pulling the css and script php lines is the blog page, that has no template on it.

How can I make it work for one single page (page-home.php, in this case)?

Comment: `is_page(about-contact)` --> `is_page('about-contact')`?

Comment: I tried is_page('page-home') since that's the template php file, but it didn't work. What exact page name should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`is_page()` requires an integer, string, or array as input. In your case, it looks like you want to provide the slug of the page, which should be in quotes:

```
if (is_page('about-contact')) {...
```

If you're trying to detect the front page, use `is_front_page()` instead of `is_page()`

Source: [`is_page()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/), [`is_front_page()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_front_page/)

Answer (score 1):

Hugo
I think you just made grammar error.
You should use

```
is_page('about-contact')
```

Instead of:

```
is_page(about-contact)
```

Comment: I tried is_page('page-home') since that's the template php file, but it didn't work. What exact page name should I use?

Comment: @HugoMoutinho use the page slug, not the template name

Comment: @Spartacus in this case it's the front page, so i'm not sue what to use

Comment: Just discovered the is_front_page() =D
Thanks a lot anyway!